# I need to read Button's text as Xpath

Tags: html, xpath

i need to read the price of the mobile from the https://paytm.com/shop/p/lg-g3-beat-d722k-CMPLXLG_G3BEAT_8GB_BLACK Orange button which is 15199 as of now for this mobile, I'm using an xpath expression like

```
//*[@id="midd-container-inner"]/div/div[2]/div[6]/div[1]/div[1]/button[1]/span[2]
```

but it's not working, please assist.

Comment: What environment do you use Xpath in? `15199` cannot be found in the source HTML of that page. And tell us what you mean by "not working".

Answer (score 0):

XPath expression is correct, just add text() function to it:

```
//*[@id="midd-container-inner"]/div/div[2]/div[6]/div[1]/div[1]/button[1]/span[2]/text()
```